# Angular observable sub and get object wont work

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the value of an object instead of query the server so many times.

But what am I missing or doing wrong?

I have the following in service:

```
  user$: Observable<any>;

  private userChangeSet = new Subject<any>();


  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {
    this.user$ = this.userChangeSet.asObservable();
  }

 reloadUserData() {
    let    url = this.baseapi + '/getuser';
    return this.http.get( url)
        .map(t=>  {
          this.updateUser(t.json().user);
          return t.json();
        });
  }
 updateUser(object) {
    this.userChangeSet.next(object);
  }
```

Is there a way I can call it like this in another component?

```
if (this.customservice.user.cash < 3000) {

    } else {

    }
```

when the result of t.json().user is

`{username: username, cash: 1}` ?

Also, why wont this work?

```
 this.customservice.user$.subscribe((value) => {
      this.xxx= value;
    });
```

Because here it says `user$` is not defined

To info. im calling reloagUserData on login.  im not looking to call it again. im just looing to call the user variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would point out is that you are not declaring the `Subject`.

```
 user$: Observable<any>;

 private userChangeSet = new Subject<any>(); // You were missing this! :D

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {
    this.user$ = this.userChangeSet.asObservable();
  }
```

> is there a way i can call it like this in another component?

You are close:

```
private userData = this.reloadUserData(); // This returns {username: username, cash: 1} right?

if (this.userData.cash < 3000) {
    // Do stuff   
} else {
   // Do other stuff
}
```

**Update 1:**

if you want to pass data to the components that are listening you use the method created in the **shared service**:

```
this.reloadUserData().subscribe((data) => {
   this.userData = data; // Here we retrieve the data of the user and store in in our variable userData
   this.sharedService.updateUser(this.userData);  // Here we call the method of the shared service passing our user's data
   }
);
```

What we do is:

1. We call the method that gives us the user's data
2. When we receive the data we call the method of our shared service and pass the data as a parameter
3. When we call that method we are triggering the `Observable` meaning that all the components subscribed to that method will trigger and receive the data sent as parameter. Therefore, if we are call `updateUser(data)` this will trigger all components that are subscribed to `user$` and they will receive the data.

**Update 2:**

Quick example.

**Shared Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomService {
  user$: Observable<any>;

  private userChangeSet = new Subject<any>();    

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {
    this.user$ = this.userChangeSet.asObservable();
  }

 reloadUserData() {
    let    url = this.baseapi + '/getuser';
    return this.http.get( url)
        .map(t=>  {
          this.updateUser(t.json().user);
          return t.json();
        });
  }

  updateUser(object) {
    this.userChangeSet.next(object);
  }
}
```

**Component1:**

```
this.reloadUserData().subscribe((data) => {
   this.userData = data; // Receives the data
   this.sharedService.updateUser(this.userData);  // Sends the data to the shared service
   }
);
```

**Component2:**

```
this.customservice.user$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.userData = data; // Is subscribed and listening, as soon as someone calls the method updateUser() from the shared service will get the data passed as parameter and will updated the value of userData
 });
```

Comment: I forgot to add in topic that i already had it. updated it now. It still wont work somehow.

Is it possible to get it straight from the variable itself?  so i dont have to call reloaduserdata? im calling it somewhere else.

Comment: The thing is that if you use `Observable` and `Subject ` is for using a **shared service**. A shared service is used for communicating and passing data between components. If you don't want that communication to happen and you want to do all in the same component, just create the method, gather the data and you have it. Post the full component code so I can have an idea of what you are trying to achieve please. ;)

Comment: Did you check out the other link i gave u btw? 

anyway, my idea is that stuff in the service updates the vvariable that other components subscribe to and use it further.

Comment: @maria I have updated *(again xD)* my answer with a short example. I hope this is helpful and gives you a clearer picture of how shared services are supposed to work. Good luck and have a nice day! ;)